# sql one to many relationship and get specific row from this relation

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my two tables:

**product table**

| id | product name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A |
| 2 | product B |

**authorized table**

| id | product id | Authorizer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Officer |
| 1 | 1 | Manager |
| 2 | 2 | Officer |

I want to select all products from product table which only authorized by officer. But not these product which authorized both officer and manager. Because if it authorized by officer and manager that means these product are valid or authorized. just select these product which is only authorized by officer from authorized table. Because these product still unauthorized

Comment: Sorry it's a bit unclear. You want to get all products which are only authorised by "Officer"? Or you just want to get product 2, specifically? Or what? Maybe we need a better data sample and a clearer requirement. Also it's unclear where you're stuck - what have you tried? Please show your attempt to write the SQL for this and explain the problem you're having. We're happy to help if we can, but it's not just a free write-my-code service. We're volunteers giving our free time so we generally expect that you can show that you spent some of your own time on the problem before asking us. Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understood. You want to get products that are only authorized by Officer and no one else? You want to get "product B" if it's only authorized by Officer?

Comment: I want to get "Product B" from product table which is only authorized by Officer.

Comment: That's what you wrote, but it doesn't make sense. If you want to get product B, just select it. It's already only authorized by officer.

Comment: You already said that. If it was clear from that, then (obviously) we wouldn't be asking you to clarify it! Just repeating the same phrase doesn't make it any clearer. As requested, please give a better explanation and provide a better data sample too. Your current explanation doesn't really make sense, and we are not mind-readers. If writing in English is difficult for you, please find someone to help you translate properly. Thanks.

Comment: I want to select all products from product table which only authorized by officer. But not these product which authorized both officer and manager. Because if it authorized by officer and manager that means these product are valid or authorized. just select these product which is only authorized by officer from authorized table. Because these product still unauthorized

Comment: That's better. And what have you tried? Please [edit] your question with your attempt, in order to avoid downvotes for lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM product
JOIN authorized
ON product.id = authorized.product_id
WHERE authorized.Authorized = "Officer"
AND product.id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM authorized WHERE Authorizer = "Manager")
```

I joined both tables (using the foreign key product_id, I assume) and checked that the id isn't found in the "Authorized" table if the Authorizer is "Manager"

EDIT: If there's others "Authorizer" that should be included, replace `Authorizer = "Manager"`
by `Authorizer != "Officer"`